# Return JSON response from method called in constructor Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm building a custom Auth system in Codeigniter 3.

Given this code:

```
class Base_REST extends REST_Controller
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct($config = 'rest')
    {
        parent::__construct($config);

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('Oauth');

        $this->user = $this->initUser();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function initUser()
    {
        try {
            return $this->oauth->checkBearerToken($this->head('Authorization'));
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

When an Exception is thown, I can't return a JSON like this:

```
{
 "message": "The token is not valid"
}
```

I'm trying with this, as I return JSON from Controllers:

```
catch (Exception $exception) {
   $this->response((object) [ 'message' => $exception->getMessage()], $exception->getCode());
}
```

But it shows nothing in the response body.

Does anybody know how to handle and return these errors? I have seen the using of echo's, but I don't think it's the best way as if there's any error during the execution of my code, the response body includes the echo but also the error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code exiting directly after the return and is the header content set to json ?

Example from codeigniter documentation:

```
$response = array('status' => 'OK');

$this->output
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
    ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
    ->_display();
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked to return the an error from a method init in the constructor. It doesn't work from an endpoint (a method in a controller), and I don't know why, but I'm returning the response there in a different way, so I'm no longer blocked.